# How to upload multiple files , create folder and place the files there PHP

Tags: php, forms

Ok, i can successfully upload 1 document , make it create a new folder within the main folder. Then place the file there.

However im having trouble doing multiple files to that same folder.

**I want to upload 2 documents and look like this:**

docs/1/ and then the files here.

**what it looks like:**

docs/1

**HTML:**

```
   <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:<br/>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br/>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$number = 1;
$target_dir = "docs/";
$new = mkdir($target_dir . $number . "/");
$target_file = $target_dir . $number . "/";

$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        foreach($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] as $file => $uploaded_file){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file . $uploaded_file);
        }
}
?>
```

Any Ideas?

EDIT WORKING:

```
        <input type="file" name="pictures[]" /><br/>
        <input type="file" name="pictures[]" /><br/>
        <input type="file" name="pictures[]" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />

    </form>

$target_dir = "docs/";
$dir=glob($target_dir."/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$number = count($dir) + 1;
$new = mkdir($target_dir . $number . "/");
$target_file = $target_dir . $number . "/";


foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["name"] as $key => $Name) 
{
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_file . "$name");
}
```

Comment: `im having trouble` how does the trouble manifest? - read: more info pls; (also you file-inputs have the same name)

Comment: You have 2 input fields with the same name.

Comment: sorry i meant to take out the $new = even though it still creates the 1 folder.
and i know i have the same name, i though thats why i would foreach through them?

Answer (score 0):

First change your file input to (note the id should be unique for all elements to avoid javascript problems):

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload_0">
```

Since you want to upload an array of files.

```
foreach($_FILES['fileToUpload'][$name] as $index=>$uploaded_file) {
    move_uploaded_file(
          $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$index], 
         $target_file.$uploaded_file);
}
```

**Update: Had a momentary mix in languages and file handling logic.**

Comment: thanks for your help, however this didnt work. it still created the folder 1, but then through all the errors i checked for with $uploadOk variable

Comment: @user3620531, Its very annoying when people say the answer "didn't work." Maybe it didn't solve the whole problem because you have a ton of errors in your code. That doesn't mean it didn't work. You're lucky anyone even posted an answer since "debug my code for me" demands are off-topic. So be more respectful.

Comment: hang on i was respectful. I said thank you for your help, i said it didnt resolve the issue and said what it did do/

Comment: Do you want to create different folders?

Comment: ive done it now, as seen in my edit at top of page :)